# C-Code...trying to combine a while loop with an OR operator to check if the input number is prime or not

Tags: c

Hey guys so this is the ques which i have coded but its not working properly..i cant seem to understand where am i going wrong..
Write a program that determines if a number that the user has entered is a prime 
number. The program will continue to ask for numbers until the user enters a 
value less than 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
   int num;
   int count = 1;
   bool check = true;


   do{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    count = num - 1;
    bool check = false;

   while (count > 1 || num % count == 0){
        check = true;
   count--;
   }
   if (check == true){
    printf("%d is a prime number\n", num);
   }
   else
    printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);

  }
   while (num > 2);
}
```

Comment: You should probably break the loop after you find one factor. You probably also perform better if you count up (many more numbers are divisible by 2 than by 2,000,000).  In fact, you only need to work up to the square root of the number.

Comment: Also after you check divisibility by two you don't need to check for any other even number because they are all divisible by two.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (count > 1 || num % count == 0){
     check = true; // <-
     count--;
}
```

On the indicated line you set `check` to `true` - this means that if the body of the loop executes even once, `check` will be true after the loop and the program will indicate that the number is prime. What you should do instead is show the number as prime iff the entire loop runs to completion.

The loop condition is also wrong; `num % count == 0` indicates that the number is *not* prime, so you can stop checking if that is true. (Hint: you can terminate the loop from within using `break`)

Also if the user enters `2` or less, the checks will still run before the outer loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want your while loop to look like this:

```
   bool prime = true;
   while (count > 1 && prime) {
        prime = ((num % count) != 0);
        count--;
   }
```

The way you wrote it will assign check to true on the first iteration, regardless of num's primality.

Comment: Would it be better to rename the boolean variable to 'prime'?

Answer (score -1):

Say

int num = 3;

or whatever number you want bigger than 2

instead of

int num;

This is to make use you enter the loop.

Comment: sorry...i coudnt understand that...how does the code change..if i do what u r saying?